# Pushing to an array in a php class creates a new field

Tags: php, arrays, class

as described in the title, my created method to push values to an array field of the Artist php class creates a new field and it does not push anything to the array.

Example:

Artist.php:

```
<?php
      class Artist {

          // properties
          public $id;
          public $profile_id;
          public $show_types = array();

          // constructor
          public function __construct($id, $profile_id) {
              $this->id = $id;
              $this->profile_id = $profile_id;
          }

         // setters
         public function add_show($show) {
         array_push($this->$show_types, $show);
        }
?>
```

Calling the `add_show` function in another file:

```
// create Artist
$artist = new Artist("1234", "1232");

// add event type
$artist->add_show($event_category); // here event_category == 16
```

Instead of adding `$event_category` (16) to the currently empty array, the artist object will look like this:

```
id : "1234"
profile_id : "1232"
"" : null
show_types : []
```

I also tried to use `$this->$show_types[] = $show`, but it yields the same result.

How can I push values to this array using the `add_show` method?

Comment: `$this->$show_types` should be `$this->show_types`! (and this throws a NOTICE, so switch on error_reporting for ALL!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing properties/attributes in a PHP class is done without the use of the $ sign. If you remove that it should fix it. Try:

```
array_push($this->show_types, $show);
```

or

```
$this->show_types[] = $show;
```

Using the $ when accessing the property is asking PHP to find a property with the value assigned in the variable you've used eg:

```
class MyClass
{
    public $myProperty = 'value';
}

$class = new MyClass();
echo $class->myProperty;

// is the same as:
$dynamicVar = 'myProperty';
echo $class->$dynamicVar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a `$` after the arrow :
`array_push($this->show_types, $show);`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the leading dollar sign before show_types here:

```
array_push($this->$show_types, $show);
```

Should be:

```
array_push($this->show_types, $show);
```

Comment: Is this acceptable to do? like `$this->to = array();
    foreach ($to as $key => $user) {
      $usrEmail = $user . '@somedomain.com';
      array_push($this->to, $usrEmail);
    }`

Comment: According to the php manual, the performance is better if you use $array[] = $variable for adding a single value to an array. So in your case: `$this->to[] = $usrEmail`